# A problem about fundamental solution of Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

I would like to derive a solution to the following equation in $R^{3}$:

$$-\Delta u(x) + e^{u(x)} - e^{-u(x)} = \delta(x)$$where $\Delta$ is the Laplace Operator and $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac's delta function.

I know how to solve $-\Delta u(x) = \delta(x)$ in the sense of weak convergence but I'm stuck on the exponential term of the equation above.

Comment: This problem is highly nonlinear. The problem is thus much harder than the simple Laplace equation which you compare it to. Could you explain a bit more about the context? (Otherwise, you might not obtain any answer to this rather hard problem)

Comment: One of the consequences of the nonlinearity of the problem, pointed out by @Fabian, is that its solvability, when the initial/boundary/source data is a measure is not guaranteed. See for example H. Brezis and A. Friedman; [Nonlinear parabolic equations involving measures as initial conditions](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~brezis/PUBlications/096journal.pdf), J. Math. Pures Appl. 62 (1983), p. 73-97 for parabolic equations.

Comment: I guess it is reasonable to derive a solution that is radially symmetric, which reduces the equation to a nonlinear ODE. My attempt is to first solve the homogeneous ODE with right hand side being zero, i.e $-\frac{d^{2}u}{dr^{2}}-\frac{2}{r}u(r)+e^{u(r)}-e^{-u(r)}=0$. Then hopefully I can pick some terms in the general solution which has a singularity at zero leading to a candidate solution. However, I don't know how to solve the ODE.